# Bootstrap Navbar in a customized table

Tags: html, responsive-design, bootstrap-4, navbar, css-tables

I am trying to create a header on a website that consists of a **table with two columns**.
The **column** on the **left** should have **an only row** with the Logo, instead, the **column** on the **right** should have **two rows**.
The first row should have the contacts of the socials ,
while the second and final row should have a responsive **navbar** ( aligned on the right obviously ).

Is it possible to obtain this with **Bootstrap**?

One solution I thought about could be a table with two columns, with the row on the left consisting of the logo, and the row on the right that consists of the socials links.
Then below that table I would implement the usual responsive navbar.

Obviously I rather prefer to implement the first solution, but if a solution with Bootstrap is not possible I will probably go for the second solution.

I would gladly appreciate any advice or comment that is positive toward that goal.

Thank you so much for your time!

This is the code I got so far:

```
       <tc> 
           <tr>
               <th>Image</th>
               </tr>
        </tc>


    <tc>
        <tr>
            <th>Social</th>
        </tr>

       <tr>

        <td>
        <nav class ="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-expand-sm ">
        <button type = "button" class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#topNav"> <span class="navbar-toggler-icon" ></span> </button>
            <div id="topNav" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item active"><a href="index.html" class="nav-link"> Home </a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="gusti.html" class="nav-link">I nostri gelati</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="storia.html" class="nav-link"> La nostra storia</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="qualita.html" class="nav-link"> Perchè così buono</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="dovesiamo.html" class="nav-link"> Trovaci </a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav> 
        </td>
    </tr>
</tc>

  </table>
```

Comment: Post the code that you have tried so far

Comment: Like one of the websites I built: https://wongsbuildingsupply.com ?

Comment: @DavidLiang Yes pretty much the same

Comment: @Themes.guide Also, I added my temp code.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pure Bootstrap solution to get you started:
https://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/djaNgo

The simplified code showing the grid layout is

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">logo</div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-end">social links</div>
        <div class="row justify-content-end">
                <!-- navbar here -->
        </div>  <!-- row -->
      </div>    <!-- container -->
    </div>      <!-- col-md-9 -->
  </div>        <!-- row -->
</div>          <!-- container -->
```

As you can probably see, if you want to build this using native Bootstrap classes you would have a row with two columns.

The left-hand column holds the logo, and then in the right-hand column you have a nested container which has rows for your social links and your navbar.

I've used the class of `.justify-content-end` to right-align the social links and the nav-bar.

I hope this helps!